# How many ways to get to cell $(n,m)$ from $(0,0)$ in a matrix of size $nm$, provided that you can only move right or down one cell?

Tags: sequences-and-series, dynamic-programming

I see that if we call $f(x,y)$ the total number of way to get to cell $(x,y)$ from $(0,0)$ , then the number itself is the sum of the number of ways to get $(x-1,y)$ and $(x, y-1)$.

Then $f(x,y)=f(x-1,y)+f(x,y-1)$ with $f(0,i)=f(j,0)=1, 0<i<n+1$ and $0<j<m+1$.

If I solve the $n^{th}$ term of the recursive formula, the complexity would be $O(n^2)$. How to find the general formula to down it to $O(1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\def\bl#1{{\color{blue}{#1}}}$
$\def\rd#1{{\color{red}{#1}}}$
$\def\gr#1{{\color{green}{#1}}}$
In general, it is $f(x,y) = {x+y\choose x}$, you can use the classical recurrence relation for the binomial
$$f(x,y) = {x+y\choose x} = {x+(y-1)\choose x}+{(x-1)+y\choose x-1}=f(x,y-1)+f(x-1,y)$$
If we plot it we'll see pascal's triangle pretty clearly
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
 \bl 1  & \rd 1  & \gr 1   & \bl 1 & \rd 1\\\hline
 \rd 1  & \gr 2  & \bl 3 & \rd 4  & \gr 5\\\hline
 \gr 1  & \bl 3  & \rd 6 & \gr{10} & \bl{15}\\\hline
 \bl 1  & \rd 4  & \gr{10} & \bl{20}& \rd{35}\\\hline
 \rd 1  & \gr{5}  & \bl{15} &\rd{35} &\gr{70}
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to counting the number of sequences $D,R$ (down,right) containing $n$ "downs" and $m$ "rights".

Consider such a sequence, it is $m+n$ characters long and is uniquely determined by the position of the $m$ "rights" in it (because then you are forced to use "downs" in all other positions). The number of ways to position these $m$ "rights" in our $n+m$ "slots" is exactly ${m + n} \choose m$.